# Fuzzy search with redis om & node js

Tags: node.js, redis, node-redis

I have been trying to implement fuzzy search in redis search, redis om with node js.
I've gone through articles like [this](https://redis.com/blog/what-is-fuzzy-matching/) but I have not managed to fix it.

This is my code sample of the search that I am currently implementing.

```js
    let searchResults = await repository.search()
        .where("country").equal(correctCountry)
        .where("city").equal(city.toLocaleLowerCase())
        .and("descriptionAndStreet")
        .matches(placedescription + "*").return.page(0, 20)
```

I would like to implement fuzzy search when searching the "placedescription".

Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution

> Redis OM does not have a fluent interface for fuzzy matching. However, you can always do a raw search (https://github.com/redis/redis-om-node/#running-raw-searches) and pass in pretty much any query you want:

```
    let query = `@country:{${correctCountry}} @city:{${city}} @descriptionAndStreet:%Whatyouwanttosearch%`

    let places = await placeRepository.searchRaw(query).return.page(0, 10)
```

If you want to search with more than one word, ie space separated

```
    let query = `@country:{${correctCountry}} @city:{${city}} 
     @descriptionAndStreet:%What% %you% %want% %to% %search%`
```

If you get issues with that you can try removing the spaces in between

```
    %What%%you%%want%%to%%search%
```